# LangChain not using tools every time

Tags: python, azure, openai-api, langchain, azure-openai

I am building a LangChain application using OpenAI.

I am using 3 tools-

1. Two tools are pdf based tools, reading pdf and finding similarity scores with the user query
2. One tool is excel based tool, reading pdf and finding similarity scores with the user query

But when I asked a question that should have been answered using a pdf tool, it is giving me generic answer, not using any tool.

It goes into the thought and thinks not to use any tool.

```
> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
Thought: Do I need to use a tool? No
```

Then it gives a generic answer. It does not happen with every question, but for some.

For your reference, this is how I am initialising the agent.

```
system_message = """<system message>"""

memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True)

agent_chain = initialize_agent(
    [pdf_tool_1, pdf_tool_1, excel_tool],
    llm,
    agent=AgentType.CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
    verbose=True,
    memory=memory,
    handle_parsing_errors=True,
    return_intermediate_steps=False,
    max_iterations=5,
    agent_kwargs={
        "system_message": system_message
    }
)
```

Strangely, if I use a `AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION`, it works as expected.

However, I can't use `ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION` as it has to be a conversational agent.

How to make sure it uses the tool(s) even with `CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION` and if it does not find anything relevant, it should not give any generic answer?